# UITableView (inside UIScrollView) didSelectRowAtIndexPath: not being called on first tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a non scrollable `UITableView` inside an `UIScrollView`. And I'm having the problem that when I touch a row, the callback `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is not being called on the first tap, but after the first tap everithing works.

A few considerations:

- After the first tap, the table view works normally, every tap works in every cell.
- This happens just after I scroll the UIScrollView. If I don't scroll the UIScrollView, this never happens.
- I have overriden the UIScrollView's `touchesShouldBegin:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event inContentView:(UIView *)view` and the event does pass throw here, the `view` is a `UITableViewCellContentView` effectively.

I just don't know why the event is not been sent to the `UITableView` on the first time, and on the following ones it does.

Comment: Double check to make sure you don't use – tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: instead of didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: @Vig Yup, after the first Tap my implementation of didSelectRowAtIndexPath is been called.

Comment: Why are you embedding non-scrollable table view in scroll view in the first place?

Comment: Does anything happen when you tap on a cell? Pushing a ViewController or something?

Comment: @sha Because I get use of the functionality and look of the UITableView. For example Inserting and Deleting rows dynamically without a UITableView would be very difficult to implement.

Comment: @beeef Yes indeed, when I tap the cell a new row is inserted with a UIPickerView in it.

Comment: @6rod9: My question was more about UIScrollView. What are you using scrollview for? Are you letting user scroll table view around?

Comment: @sha Because I have more content before the UITableView, I have some other UIViews on top of it, and at the bottom the IUTable view. So and the vertical content is too big to fit on the screen, that's why I need the UIScrollView.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `UIScrollView` that contains vertical content and `UITableView` as part of this content, you must at least disable scrolling on `UITableView` - otherwise it's confusing for the user when he will scroll your `mainView` and when `tableView`, and also confusing for the framework because it's not clear where to send panning gestures.

As a rule of thumb - you should avoid putting table views inside `scrollViews`, unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: The scrolling on the table view is effectively disabled. :/

Comment: How exactly it's `effectively` disabled?

Comment: I disabled the scrolling in the storyboard UITableView checkbox "Scrolling Enabled".
My guess is that the scroll view still thinks that the first tap is part of the previous scrolling events, but still have no clue why.

Comment: You need to post some code. What methods did you change in UIScrollview related to touches, what exactly you're doing there etc.

Comment: I have just overriden `touchesShouldCancelInContentView` to always return `TRUE`, and the delegate method `scrollViewDidScroll`. And in the table view the delegate method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, that method is the one that is not called on the first tap.

Answer (score 0):

Please disable scrolling of your table view and check the datasource and delegate are connected to your table view. If not follow the bellow code

```
@interface myClass ()<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.myTableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    self.myTableView.delegate = self;
    self.myTableView.dataSource = self;
}
```